# How should we test an rjs response in Rails Functional tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I test a .js.rjs response in rails(2.3.8) functional test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the simple path and verify the contents being returned seem correct with a functional test.

However, you'll probably get a lot more value from something like Capybara and Celerity that will let you do real integration testing with a live JavaScript engine and verify the RJS causes the page behave you expect.

http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/README.rdoc

Answer (score 0):

There's [assert_select_rjs](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select_rjs) in case you weren't aware of it (like I was). Its something like an `assert_tag` for RJS output.